# changing visibility on submit - only flashes visible

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying just to make the span tag appear when the submit button is pressed using the following code:

```
<form onsubmit="checkName(this);">
    <ul>
        <li>Surname<br><input type="text" name="username"><span id="surnameMissing">Surname is a required field</span></li>
        ...
        <li><input type="submit"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

My Javasrcipt:

```
function checkName(form){
    if (form.username.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("surnameMissing").style.visibility = "visible";        
    }
    return false;
}
```

The span is set initially to hidden and changed upon submission however the tag only appears for a split second then goes back to being hidden.  Any suggestions as to why this is?

Comment: You can use jQuery hide()/show() function for this. $("#surnameMissing").hide()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689832/javascript-how-to-create-a-validation-error-message-without-using-alert

Answer (score 2):

This `form` is submitted that's why you see it only for second.

You need to prevent the submit if the form is invalid - Add `return` in the attribute `onsubmit`.

Like this:

```js
function checkName(form) {
  if (form.username.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("surnameMissing").style.visibility = "visible";        
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
#surnameMissing {
  visibility:hidden;  
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkName(this);">
    <ul>
        <li>Surname<br><input type="text" name="username"><span id="surnameMissing">Surname is a required field</span></li>
        ...
        <li><input type="submit"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Another option is to pass the event to the function, then use [`.preventDefault()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) like this:

```js
function checkName(form, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (form.username.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("surnameMissing").style.visibility = "visible";        
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
#surnameMissing {
  visibility:hidden;  
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="checkName(this, event);">
    <ul>
        <li>Surname<br><input type="text" name="username"><span id="surnameMissing">Surname is a required field</span></li>
        ...
        <li><input type="submit"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didnt appreciate just returning false in the function was working :)

Comment: My pleasure ;) Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) the answer so it will help to other people.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the form is submitted once you click submit. To prevent it from submitting, use this code.

```
<script>
    function checkName(form){
    if(form.username.value == ""){
        document.getElementById("surnameMissing").style.visibility = "visible";        
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
</script>
<form onsubmit="return checkName(this);">
<ul>
    <li>Surname<br><input type="text" name="username"><span style="visibility:hidden;" id="surnameMissing">Surname is a required field</span></li>
    ...
    <li><input type="submit"></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prevent your form from being submitted by adding `event.preventDefault();` below your function name. And then make sure you will submit your form when `username.value == ""` returns false.

```
function checkName (form) {
    // prevent from submission
    event.preventDefault();

    if(form.username.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("surnameMissing").style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        // Submit on successful validation
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

You can also add `event.preventDefault()` before you call your function in the onsubmit attribute of your form.

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); checkName(this);"> ... </form>
```

Personally, I would also like to trap the event during the input itself. Not just during submission.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <ul>
        <li>Surname: <br><input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <span id="surnameMissing">Surname is a required field</span></li>
        <li><input type="submit"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and the javascript

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(this.username.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("surnameMissing").style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        this.submit();
    }
});

var inputUsername = document.getElementById("username");
inputUsername.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if(this.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("surnameMissing").style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("surnameMissing").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
});
```