# Displaying error messages without using alert in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to display a validation error message without using an alert box. But its not working. Previously I've used "innerHTML" successfully. But i don't understand why it doesn't work here. This is my code.

```js
function validate()
{
  if(document.regform.fname.value.length=="")
    {
       document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="error";
    }    
}
```

```html
<header>
   <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
</header>
<div class="div1"><img src="img.jpg" width="250px"></div>
<div class="div2" id="div2">
  <form name="regform" onsubmit="return validate()">
     <label><input type="text" name="fName" id="fna"></label>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" >
     <p id="error"></p>
  </form>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Let me guess, your form just flashes and then reloads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript how to create a validation error message without using alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689832/javascript-how-to-create-a-validation-error-message-without-using-alert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. Firstly the name is `fName` but you are using `fname` and then you must compare `length` by an integer value not empty string.

Also you would like to stop the submission if an error occurred. Hence you return a `false` if there is an error.
Try this.

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.regform.fName.value.length == '0') {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "error";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>SIGN UP</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="div2" id="div2">
    <form name="regform" onsubmit="return validate()">

      <label><input type="text" name="fName" id="fna"></label>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up">
      <p id="error"></p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: indent your answer, and make a snippet

Comment: @Anup it worked. Seems i have to be more careful while coding.. thank you